# Get element from array of JSON postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a column x with data type `jsonb`

and the value looks like:

```
[  
    [{"string":"whateverstring1"}],
    [{"string":"whateverstring2"}]
]
```

**How to return each element of the array?**

Something like this:
"**whateverstring1**","**whateverstring2**"

Answer (score 11):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=480f73d41d2a835acad7063fd5d788a6)

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb) -> 0 -> 'string' 
FROM (
    SELECT '[[{"string":"whateverstring1"}],[{"string":"whateverstring2"}]]'::jsonb
) s
```

1. `jsonb_array_elements` extract each element into one row
2. `-> 0` gives the first element of the nested arrays which is `{"string":"whateverstring1"}`
3. `-> 'string'` gives the value of the elements